# how to understand remote "origin" fetch setting in .git/conf file?

Tags: git, github, git-config

I saw the command in `.git/config` when I learn pull & request from [this article](https://gist.github.com/Chaser324/ce0505fbed06b947d962#checking-out-and-testing-pull-requests).

`fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/pull/origin/*`

I open my config file which is different as this `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

After I modify `fetch` setting line as the article read and run those git commands:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b 1 pull/origin/1
```

The `config` file automatic append this:

```
[branch "1"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/pull/1/head
```

Could someone can explain the means and difference settings of the `fetch = ...`?
Why `[branch "1"]` will be auto appended?

Thanks

Comment: `git checkout -b 1 pull/origin/1` has an effect that `pull/origin/1` is set as the upstream of  `1`. The config records this relationship.

Comment: @ElpieKay, what's the means of `pull origin`? Specify it's a pull request?

Comment: Here `refs/pull/origin/*` is a group of refs used as `pull request` by Github. The most common "built-in" refs are `refs/heads/*` as branches, `refs/tags/*` as tags and `refs/remotes/*` as remote branches. You could define your own refs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's quite a lot to unpack here. Let's start from the beginning.

### The Refspec

The value of the `fetch` setting is what's called a [*refspec*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec), a special Git syntax used to map *local* branch references with *remote* ones.

It takes the form:

```
<source>:<destination>
```

In the case of `fetch`, `<source>` is a branch that exists on a *remote* repository, while `<destination>` is the branch it should map to in the *local* repository. So, for example:

```
fetch: +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

tells Git to map the `master` branch that exists in the remote repository (the *source*) to the `origin/master` branch in the local one (the *destination*).

The `+` character is optional and means that Git should update the *destination* branch even if it would require a merge commit (which shouldn't happen since you normally don't commit directly to the `origin/master` branch).

### Pull Request Branches

Now that you know about the refspec syntax, let's talk about mapping the *pull request branches* from GitHub.

As you know, every pull request gets assigned a unique number within a given repository. What you may not know, however, is that this number ends up becoming the *name of the branch* associated to the pull request.

For example, a pull request with number `42` will get a branch reference named:

```
refs/pull/42
```

Notice how pull request branches are created in a subdirectory called `pull` in the repository hosted on GitHub.

If you wanted to map *every* pull request branch that exists in the *remote* repository on GitHub to a corresponding *local* branch with the same name, you would say:

```
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/pull/origin/*
```

where `*` is a wildcard character that matches any name. With this setting, next time you do `git fetch` in your local repository, Git will download *all* branch references that exist in the `pull` directory on GitHub and create corresponding branches in the local repository under the directory `pull/origin`.

This means that for our pull request `42`, for example, the mapping becomes:

```
    GitHub        Your Repo
pull/42/head -> pull/origin/42
```

### Remote Branches

Note that the `pull/origin/*` branches—while they do exist in your local repository—are not meant for you to commit to. They're called [*remote-tracking branches*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) and are used by Git to literally keep track of a given branch that exist in a remote repository.

The documentation [says it best](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches):

> Remote-tracking branches are references to the state of remote branches.

More specifically:

> Think of them as bookmarks, to remind you where the branches in your remote repositories were the last time you connected to them.

You can't commit to a remote branch directly. If you want to move it forward, you must first create a *local* branch (i.e. one that exists *only* in your local repository) and associate it to the remote branch. From that point on, every time you do `git pull` or `git push` on that local branch, Git is going to update the corresponding remote tracking branch.

You can do that with a single command:

```
git checkout -b 42 pull/origin/42
```

This creates a *local* branch named `42` and associate it to the remote tracking branch `pull/origin/42`, which in turn is mapped to the `pull/42` branch on GitHub. Here's how it looks like:

```
 Local      Remote        GitHub
  42 -> pull/origin/42 -> pull/42
```

The relationship between *local* branch and *remote* branch is expressed in the local repository's configuration file as:

```
[branch "42"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/pull/42/head
```

The relationship between the *remote* branch and the branch that's physically on another machine (i.e. on GitHub) is expressed by using the *refspec* syntax that we looked at in the beginning.

Comment: Upvoted; but I have a few minor items to mention: while Git calls `origin/master` a *remote-tracking branch*, I think this is a poor name and have started using *remote-tracking name* instead (though I may never get anywhere in convincing everyone else to do the same :-) ). Remote-tracking names internally are *only* those starting with `refs/remotes/` so if you name things `refs/pull/*`, those aren't remote-tracking names either, they're a new namespace entirely. Also, it's worth being careful with branch names like `-b 123`: when you hit 4 digits, they get ambiguous vs hash IDs.

Comment: @torek I like the idea of not calling them *branches* since you never commit to them directly. *Remote-tracking names* is fine but I feel *name* is a bit too generic. Maybe *remote-tracking refs*? The ones outside the `remote` namespace could then simply be *remote refs*. Thanks for the feedback on the branch name – I agree, so I made it shorter ;)

Comment: Hi, can I push back to `pull/origin/42` remote repository to modify something for my forker?

Comment: Yes, you can as long as you have permission from the owner of the fork. You can read more about this in the [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/).