# Git point local repo to remote

Tags: git

I have existing project: my-project on both DEV and QA. Now I'm thinking of creating git repo so I can push the changes from DEV so QA can pull the changes. I don't want to delete my-project from QA and clone my-project from DEV to QA. So I am planning to do this:

On Dev:

```
$cd ~/my-project
$git init
$git add .
$git commit -m "My project"
$git remote add --track master origin ~/my-project
$git push
```

On QA:

```
$ cd ~/my-project
$git init
$git remote add origin ssh://Dev:~/my-project
$git pull
```

Will this work? Or do I miss anything? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is good (provided `ssh://Dev` does work)

All that is missing is a [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) in order to instruct your QA repo to fetch something (as explained in "[How to understand remote “`origin`” fetch setting in `.git/config` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47818561/6309)"):

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

You can then do a `git fetch`, and then create a new local `master` branch

```
git switch -c master
```

That will track automatically `origin/master`, using the new (Git 2.23+) [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) command (see "[Confused by `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)").

From there, you can `git pull` at any time.